# SurveyMonkey : How to Filter responses by custom_variables

Tags: django, python-3.x, web, surveymonkey

Is there any way to filter out responses by custom_variables?

I have set custom_varibles in weblink collector, now need to filter it by the variable I have set. Or Is their another way of setting a unique value, like email/username with weblink collector type and filter the responses by this unique value.

I am Currently redirecting to SurveyMonkey weblink with email as a custom_variable, now I need to identify the response with this email.

EDIT: Is this Possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's on our upcoming roadmap.

In the meantime, use "?c=whatever_string_you_want" and use the "custom" responses filter.